# would you ask someone to drive safe or to drive safely?

Tags: word-choice

When someone is going to drive their car somewhere, I always used to say "drive safely" to them.  Recently I was told I should say "drive safe."  Which is correct?  So it's about when to use the word SAFE and when to use the word SAFELY. Thank you.

Comment: Please search the site before asking.