# Have Americans stopped using adverbs ? eg "Eat healthy" instead of "Eat healthily"

Tags: grammaticality, american-english

I live in the UK and generally a word that adds flavour or describes a verb , will have the adverb ending applied
eg run quickly (not run quick) , eat healthily (not eat healthy) etc

But when I watch the many US TV shows on in the UK, I almost never hear Americans using adverbs in this way. They just seem to use the adjectival form of the word.

This seems to be so common as to be standard in the US. Is this viewed as correct speech in the US ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/which-is-correct-drive-safe-or-drive-safely considering the number of potential variants of this, it might be best to reword the question to focus more directly on the observed evolutionary differences between AmE and BrE

Comment: Since many Americans are, or are descended from, immigrants whose first language was not English, it is reasonable to conclude that American English is a corruption of the English spoken in England. Oh ***biscuit!*** Even local English spoken in England, is a corruption too!

Comment: Corruption? The use of eat healthy is not a corruption coming from foreign language speakers.

Comment: @Lambie please read my comment a few times, and then read it again. This question was shown as a duplicate, and a high rep deleted all the comments except mine.