# "not near as drunk" vs "not nearly as drunk"

Tags: word-usage

I actually looked at the "drive safe/ly" answers before I posted this question and remember, at the time, seeing how these were clearly two different questions.
Now, however, they seem the same. I guess I didn't think I was near as drunk as I actually was.

Solved.

---

> Near or nearly?
>
> Between "not near as drunk" and "not nearly as drunk", I can't think
>   of a compelling reason to prefer one to the other. "Not nearly"
>   *sounds* better, I think, but I wouldn't be able to say why.
>
> I imagine it comes down to whether "as" is an adverb or a preposition
>   in this phrase, but I can't think of a compelling reason to decide
>   even that one way or the other.

Comment: See the question on "drive safe" or "drive safely". https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8328/9368 Adjectives can be (and have been for centuries) used also as adverbs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is correct: "drive safe" or "drive safely"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/which-is-correct-drive-safe-or-drive-safely)

Comment: "nowhere near as drunk" is also a possibility you should bear in mind the next time you want to use this phrase. *I'm nowhere near as drunk as I'm planning to be*.

Comment: I read 'not near as drunk' in a Yorkshire accent

Comment: Not sure about Yorkshire, but certainly a regional dialect.

Answer (score 1):

*Not nearly as drunk* would be better.

*Nearly* works as the adverb that modifies *as* (another adverb). Adverbs can modify other adverbs and explain "how much."

Edited for clarity and a typo.

Comment: Would you prefer to stand nearer to the door, or more nearly? Or what about nearlier? Only in near misses and such is *near* an adjective. It's usually an adverb -- one of a different kind than *nearly* is . (And some would say that even as a preposition it's gradable, if you can fit your head around that one.)